# Is there a way to automatically serve stale bundles from a CDN?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundle, cdn

I'm working on a React/Webpack project where we run into the following problem:

We do a little bit of code splitting, so the app is essentially split into bundle A and bundle B. We'll periodically release updated versions of the app, so there will be bundles A1 and B1, then for the next version bundles A2 and B2, and so on.

If a user is viewing pages from A1, and then a new version of the app is released, but the user is still on the site with the old version, then they will request B1 which will no longer exist. Our deploy system only serves the latest bundles.

In order to try and fix this issue, we now have a CDN at `cdn.myapp.com` which stores all of the old bundle versions.

But how can we detect if a user is requesting a stale bundle so that we can serve it from the CDN? Is there a word or phrase for what I want to do?

I'm not interested in any solutions which don't preserve the old bundles (so I'm not interested in, say, forcing the user to refresh the page, since this would be poor UX).

Comment: you can introduce a cookie that tracks which version they are on. Pretty standard for any kind of ab-testing or similar. Wouldn't be retroactive tho

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.